# Regex trim or preg_replace white space including tabs and new lines

Tags: php, regex, trim

How can I use PHP to trim all white space up to "poo" and all white space afterwards?

I would like to turn this:

```
<code><div class="b-line"></div>  \t 

             \n\n\n \t \n   poo
<lol>
 n \n \n \t </code>
```

In to this:

```
<code><div class="b-line"></div>poo 
<lol>
 n</code>
```

This part will always be at the start of the string: `<code><div class="b-line"></div>`

Thanks

Edit: Sorry I should explain that the whole of the above is in a string and I *only* want to trim the whitespace *immediately after* `<code><div class="b-line"></div>` *and immediately before* `</code>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this lookahead and lookbehind based regex will work for you:

```
$str = <<< EOF
<code><div class="b-line"></div>  \t 

             \n\n\n \t \n   poo
<lol>
 n \n \n \t </code>
EOF;
$str = preg_replace_callback('#(?<=<code><div class="b-line"></div>)(.*?)(\s*<[^>]*>\s*)(.*?)(?=</code>)#is',
       create_function('$m',
       'return str_replace(array("\n", "\t", " "), "", $m[1]).$m[2].str_replace(array("\n", "\t", " "), "", $m[3]);'),
       $str);
var_dump ( $str );
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
string(51) "<code><div class="b-line"></div>poo
<lol>
 n</code>"
```

Comment: Will you always need `new line and space around <lol>` or it could be any other string not just `<lol>`?

Comment: hi anubhava, no, <lol> was just an example, it will be any code in the middle

Comment: Alright edited my answer based on your comments, now it instead of `<lol>` it can be any other string as well like `<foo>` or `<bar>`.

Comment: hmm its close but still doesn't seem to replace new lines... this string is coming from a <textarea> and i've tried adding \r to the replace array too but its not working... any further ideas? many thanks

Comment: string(81) "test\n\n<code><div class="b-line"></div>\n \n lol\n\n <b>bold</b>\n\n \n</div>\ntest"

Comment: Aren't you supposed to have `</code>`? In your test string in last comment you don't have that.

Answer (score 4):

```
$str = trim($str, "\t\n");
```

See [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Comment: I've updated to explain better, I don't want to trim all of the lines etc. I only want to trim the whitespace immediately after <code><div class="b-line"></div> and immediately before </code>

Answer (score 3):

`preg_*` functions provides [whitespace escape sequence `\s`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php), which you can use, so you're regex would be:

```
$regexp = '~...>\\s*([^<]*?)\\s*<~m'
```

Maybe you will need to use `[\\s$]` instead of just `\\s`, I'm nor sure how PCRE handles newlines in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

> I only want to trim the whitespace immediately after `<code><div class="b-line"></div>` and immediately before `</code>`

Can be done with:

```
preg_replace(',(?|(<code><div class="b-line"></div>)\s+|\s+(</code>)),', '$1', $str);
```

[Example here](http://ideone.com/EpexZ).

---

If the `<code>` tag only occurs at beginning/end of string you would want to anchor the expression with `^` and `$`:

```
(?|^(<code><div class="b-line"></div>)\s+|\s+(</code>)$)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Vyktor's answer is almost correct. If you just run `echo preg_replace('/\s/', '', $s);` against your string (which is `$s`) you will get:

```
<code><divclass="b-line"></div>poo<lol>n</code>
```

Test snippet:

```
  <?php
  $s = <<<EOF
  <code><div class="b-line"></div>




      poo
  <lol>
   n

  </code>      
  EOF;      
  echo preg_replace('/\s/', '', $s);      
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Darren, it's not quite what I want to do.. I only want to trim space after the </div> up to the next character, then space before the </code>

Comment: Because I use this string as <code> block and the extra characters or white space cause new lines to show up if the user types them in.