# split string into array and trim middle?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string that is something like this:

```
$str="

<code>

  lol
      test

</code>

test";
```

I want to trim the text that is within the tags so that I end up with this:

```
$str="

<code>lol
      test</code>

test";
```

Is there a way that I can split this out in to a 3 array pieces and so a simple trim() on the text in the middle?

many thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex trim or preg_replace white space including tabs and new lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129368/regex-trim-or-preg-replace-white-space-including-tabs-and-new-lines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it. What it does is looks for a `<tag>` followed by any number of spaces and trims until it finds another non-space character. It then removes any number of spaces before a closing `</tag>`.

```
preg_replace(array(
    '/(<[a-zA-Z]+>)[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]])/m',
    '/[[:space:]]*(<\/[a-zA-Z]+>)/m',
), array(
    '\1\2',
    '\1',
), $str);
```

See it in action: http://codepad.org/Stmd32QL

**Edit**

This would look for only `<code>` tags.

```
preg_replace(array(
    '/(<code>)[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]])/mi',
    '/[[:space:]]*(<\/code>)/mi',
), array(
    '\1\2',
    '\1',
), $str);
```

Comment: Many thanks, but could you make this so that it looks for just "<code>" in particular?

Comment: @Tim Updated my answer. As it was pointed out, this probably isn't the best way to achieve what you want. Look into [DOM parsers](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not the correct solution for this and you should use a html parsing library if you want to get the best results. However if you're okay with the issues of parsing html with regex; this should do it:

```
<?php
$string = "

<code>

  lol
      test

</code>

test";

$pattern = '/(<([a-z]+)>)\s*(.+)\s*(<\/\2>)/ms';

$new_string = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($m) {
    return $m[1].trim($m[3]).$m[4];
  }, $string);


var_dump($new_string);
```

Results in:

```
$ php test.php
string(35) "

<code>lol
      test</code>

test"
```

Note that the html tag pattern is simplified for your exemple here, and you would have to modify it if you needed to support things like, say, `<coDe style="color: red;">`