# Trim substrings within PHP regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, whitespace

I have a string which may contain a pattern like:

```
LINK([anchor text],[link])
```

What I would like to do is transform this expression into a HTML link:

```
<a href="link">anchor text</a>
```

At the moment, I'm performing the replacement with the following PHP snippet:

```
$string = 'LINK(  some anchor text    ,   http://mydomain.com  )';
$search = '/LINK\s*\(\s*(.+),\s*([^\s]+)\s*\)/';
$replace = '<a href="$2">$1</a>';
preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

The problem I'm facing are the spaces after the anchor text. Fortunately, in HTML multiple spaces are interpreted as a single space, but in this example I would however show a link with a (underlined) annoying space. Is there any way to trim this anchor text? I can't treat it as the "link" substring, since it may contain spaces.

Comment: Perhaps [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) with some code in the callback to handle trimming as well as the actual replace

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex trim or preg\_replace white space including tabs and new lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129368/regex-trim-or-preg-replace-white-space-including-tabs-and-new-lines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the anchor text cannot contain commas or more than 1 space in a row, you could perhaps use:

```
LINK\s*\(\s*([^\s,]+(?:\s[^\s,]+)*)\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*\)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fH8yA1)

Instead of `.+`, I'm using `[^\s,]+(?:\s[^\s,]+)*` which will match one word, and more words separated by space (where a word is a series of non-space characters with at least one character).

Also changed your negated class `[^\s]` which appears later on to `\S`.

Comment: Nice job @Jerry! That's what I was looking for. I've slightly edited the pattern to `LINK\s*\(\s*([^\s]+(?:\s[^\s]+)*)\s*,\s*(\S+)\s*\)` because my intention was to allow commas too within anchor text. Thank you!

Comment: @Giorgio Okay, cool! Without those commas, you might be getting a little more overheads, but if that makes the regex more flexible! Note that since you removed the commas, you can actually use `\S` instead of `[^\s]` :)

Answer (score 1):

You could make the relevant quantifiers *lazy*, that they don't eat up the white-spaces before `,` or `)`:

```
'/LINK\(\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*([^\s]+?)\s*\)/'
```

by adding an `?` after `+`.

[Test](http://regexr.com?37tar)

Comment: @Giorgio Me and Arphrial were thinking same at same time :)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do in this case is change the first group to group lazily.

```
$search = '/LINK\s*\(\s*(.+),\s*([^\s]+)\s*\)/';
```

Can be changed to:

```
$search = '/LINK\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*([^\s]+)\s*\)/';
```

Notice the question mark after the plus. This tells the program to match it using the least number of characters.

In this case, the *laziest* it can match is a string, followed by any number of spaces, then a comma.

In the original case, it would be matching *greedily*. This means that it will try to match the maximum number of characters possible, causing the `.+` to match all characters up to the comma.

Here is [a regex101](http://regex101.com/r/oV5gE7) of the code.

Comment: Since I think that you and Jonny5 were writing at the same time, +1 for you too! Thanks.